# Error when compiling c++ program with SFML

Tags: c++, makefile, sfml, game-development

I am learning SFML with c++, when I am compiling with `mingw32-make` it is giving error because I am using class file

this is the error:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `Game::Game()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `Game::running() const'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Game::pollEvent()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `Game::update()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `Game::render()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `Game::~Game()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `Game::~Game()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'link' failed
mingw32-make: *** [link] Error 1
```

this is the code

main.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
Game mygame;
while (mygame.running()){
    //poll event
    mygame.pollEvent();
    //update
    mygame.update();
    //render
    mygame.render();
}
//End of the game
return 0;
```

}

Game.h:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
using namespace sf;
class Game{
private:
//variable 
RenderWindow *window;
Event ev;
VideoMode videoMode;
//private function
void initVar();
void initWindow();

public:
    //constructor / Destructor
    Game();
    virtual ~Game();
    //Accessors
    const bool running() const;
    //functions
    void pollEvent();
    void update();
    void render();
};
#endif
```

Game.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
void Game::initVar(){
     this->window = nullptr;
}
void Game::initWindow(){
    this->videoMode.height = 600;
    this->videoMode.width = 800; 
    this->window = new RenderWindow(this->videoMode, "Game 1", Style::Titlebar | Style::Close | Style::Resize);
}
//constructure
Game::Game(){
    this->initVar();
    this->initWindow();
}
//Destructure
Game::~Game(){
    delete this->window;
}
//Accsessors
const bool Game::running() const{
    return this->window->isOpen();
}
//Functions
void Game::pollEvent(){
    while(this->window->pollEvent(this->ev)){
            switch(this->ev.type){
                case Event::Closed:
                    this->window->close();
                    break;
                case Event::KeyPressed:
                    if(this->ev.key.code == Keyboard::Escape){
                        this->window->close();
                        break;
                     }
            }
        }
}
void Game::update(){
    this->pollEvent();
}
void Game::render(){
    this->window->clear(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
    //Draw game objects
    this->window->display();
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: compile link

compile:
    g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp
link:
    g++ main.o -o main -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
```

Comment: You're not compiling game.cpp, (but I don't know the exact syntax to add this), so the linker is looking for the implementation of these functions and is unable to find them. Also you're using raw pointers, check out c++ unique_ptr https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not compiling game.cpp, so the linker is looking for the implementation of these functions and is unable to find them. You can update your makefile as follows

```
compile:
    g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp -c Game.cpp
link:
    g++ main.o Game.o -o main -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
```

and it should work

Comment: Now it is showing this error

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-systemm
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe": *** [link] Error 1
PS E:\programming\sfmlproject> clscr `

Comment: problem solved, thanks <3

Makefile should be 
`all: compile link

compile:
 g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp -c Game.cpp
link:
 g++ main.o Game.o -o main -o Game -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system`

Comment: Nice, think I've fixed but I'm also now on my phone